# Browse zip files in mac using HTML file input

Tags: javascript, html, macos, input

Using the following code, I was browsing the zip files in macintosh, but it was highlighting all the ms office documents while browse dialog filtering the files by file extension. But i want to know how to browse the zip files only.

```
<input type="file" name="browseFile" accept=".zip,application/x-compressed,application/x-zip-compressed,application/zip,multipart/x-zip"/>
```